# Will SD-card in an RPi 4 always be faster than USB 3.0 writing/reading to an installed web-server?

Tags: sd-card, pi-4, web-server, usb3

Setup: RPi 4 with LAMP on [IT sucks DK](https://it.sucks.dk)

My SD card is quite quick sure (it's a Class 10 too and all) but my question is this:

- Would there be increased performance if I hosted my web-server files on a USB 3.0 HDD/SSD instead af my Class 10 SD-card on the Pi?

Anyone tried this yet?

EDIT: Another thought: If I want people to be able to upload and download larger than 1GB files wouldn't it be practical AND faster to be reading and writing these files to a DIR on the USB 3.0 SSD instead of the SD-card which is only 16GB all in all anyways and I do have 500/500 Mbit fiber line at my full disposal for the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> USB flash drives can reach up 33MBytes/s, but there seem to be some
>   limitations in the NAND itself so it will come down to the type of
>   stick you get. However, the sd-card bus speed can reach up to 20MB/s
>   read on the raspberry pi. So, the better choice here is a high-class
>   USB 2.0 USB flash drive.
>
> On the other hand, the payment would be concerned. It cost much less
>   to buy USB 2.0 USB flash drive instead of a UHS-3/Class 10 sd-card.
>
> In conclusion, I see little benefit in booting from a USB flash stick,
>   the price, and the speed. [Source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107846/44221)

If you compare SD-Card and USB 2.0, the USB 2.0 port is much faster. Obviously, USB 3.0 has a much much faster speed. The USB 3.0 is approximately 10 times faster than USB 2.0.

You may found that SSD drives are better for hosting BUT take a look at [this link](https://www.wp-tweaks.com/you-probably-dont-need-ssd-hosting/).

Comment: Thx...  I will take a look at it tonight.

Comment: I found your link very informative reading - I will mark your post as answer to my question because it's so extensive :-)

Answer (score 1):

The SDCard interface is extremely slow compared to a USB 2.0 hard disk on my RPI3Bs.

So a USB 3.0 SSD on a RPi4B is going to be even faster (USB 3.0 is faster, SSD is faster).

Comment: I heard something about that the USB-controller and other controllers are one and the same and therefore one controller could have problems when dealing with both the high mbit/s on the LANinterface AND transfering files to the USB 3.0 external SSD. Is this a valid thought?

Comment: The USB 3.0 controller is on a PCIe v1 interface on a RPi4, so you won't have the overlapping with the ethernet problem (unlike older RPis).

Comment: GReat to know - thanks for clearing that up... it's been bugging me.